# Is the sentence "She's been shopping for how long?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence "She's been shopping for how long?" grammatically correct? I'm concerned that it sounds too awkward.

In context, it is obvious that I am asking how long Thora went to the shop for (it's not just an exclamation):

- Where's Thora and how long has she been away?
- Thora went shopping ages ago.
- She's been shopping for how long?

Comment: i've lost track even of what i'm trying to ask now

Comment: People use that form when speaking instead of saying: how long has she been etc. Yes, it's grammatical in spoken English.

Answer (score 3):

It may be grammatically correct, but it's not idiomatic.

"She's been shopping for *how long*?" would only be used to request a *clarification* of the length of the shopping trip when the asker either didn't hear, or can't believe what he or she heard.

Ex:

"My sister has been at the mall for sixteen hours."
"She's been shopping for how long!?"

"My sister has been shopping for mumble-mumble-mumble hours"
"Sorry, I didn't hear you.  She's been shopping for *how* long?

Outside of these circumstances, the normal question would be phrased in the way questions are typically phrased, starting with a question word, and having an inverted verb and subject: "How long has she been shopping?"

Answer (score 3):

It's fine, although I would move "how long" to the front of the sentence:

> How long has she been shopping?
>
> How long has he been away?

There's nothing wrong with putting it elsewhere, but because it delays the question it sometimes adds a nuance of drama or anticipation:

> Police Officer:  What is your occupation, Ms. Smythe?
>   Ms. Smythe:  I'm a schoolteacher.
>   Police:  And you've been a schoolteacher for **how long**?
>   Smythe:  Fifteen years.
>   Police:  And, as a schoolteacher, you teach **what subject**?
>   Smythe:  English literature.

As Juhasz mentions, adding the question words at the end of the sentence is often (but not always) used to *clarify* some earlier question.

> Police:  How long were you watching television before you say you heard the shot?
>   Witness:  About an hour.
>   Police:  I'm sorry but **how long**?  In an earlier statement you said you were watching television for fifteen minutes.